# The getMessage() function in PHP being static referenced by object?

Tags: php, oop, exception

On the PHP documentation the function getMessage of Exception class is given as:

```
final public string Exception::getMessage ( void )
```

Since there is a scope resolution operator this means it is a static function and when we catch the exceptions in catch block then we do something like

```
$e->getMessage();
```

But in PHP we cannot reference the static functions with the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope resolution operator `::` needs to be used to call static methods because there is not an associated instance to call them from.

Similarly, it is used when describing the signature of a method because there is no instance to use the `->` (object scope) operator. But it doesn't say or imply a method is static.

The `static` keyword does that. `getMessage` is not a static method, and you shouldn't call it statically. The `Exception` class has no `static` methods or properties. [Linky](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php).

Answer (score 0):

It's not because it's written with the scope resolution operator inside the PHP docs, that it is a static function.

If you watch the docs carefully, you'll see that every method is with that operator.
If you want to be sure, you need to check the docs of the object itself: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php

There you can see this:

> /* Methods */
>   public __construct ([ string $message = "" [, int $code = 0 [, Throwable $previous = NULL ]]] )
>   final public string getMessage ( void )
>   final public Exception getPrevious ( void )
>   final public mixed getCode ( void )
>   final public string getFile ( void )
>   final public int getLine ( void )
>   final public array getTrace ( void )
>   final public string getTraceAsString ( void )
>   public string __toString ( void )
>   final private void __clone ( void )

If there was a static method, it would be written here.

Another example is the DateTime object: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php
Here you can see that the keyword `static` is inside the method list.

Comment: Thankyou. So this means that scope resolution operator here wants to say that it belongs to the exception class and has nothing to do with its static nature. Thankyou once again